How to show page url in crm entries?
i have added a contact form 7 on two pages of my website and their entries are showing in the crm entries in dashboard but is there any way by which i get to know which entry is coming from which page.
can we do it with the help of hidden fields ?
i only want to see that in the crm entries in dashboard.
Thanks for your suggestions in advance.
i want to show the page url from which the leads are coming.
